# to add textview and button in each row of android listview

Tags: android, listview, button, textview

to add **textview**  and **button** in each row of android **listview** and if a button in a row is clicked only its row's textview should be edited or changed and other rows must remain unaffected

Answer (score 0):

To acquire this, you need to use custom adapter and your custom layout.

In your row XML file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button" />
```

In your base adapter, you can then set the listener to do something:

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Some other method implementation here...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Initialize the convertView here...

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_layout);
        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Row clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```